# Is there a way to update the WPF WebView's Microsoft Edge Browser version?

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I currently have Visual Studio 2019 and created a WPF app. I installed Microsoft's WebView (an updated web browser) through the Nuget Manager. I ran the app and sure enough it worked flawlessly but after checking the browser's version, it was using the old Edge 18.

My code's extremely simple as I was just testing out the browser, I just added the browser inside the Main Grid and did nothing else:

```
<Window x:Class="WebViewTrial3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebViewTrial3" 
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <controls:WebView Source="https://html5test.com/"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**What I tried:**
I tried installing the latest version of Microsoft Edge (v81) and rebuild the app. Unfortunately it still runs the old Edge 18 instead of the Edge 81.

**What I wanted to happen:**
I was expecting it to run the Microsoft Edge 81 as I was under the impression that it would simply use the latest Microsoft Edge.

Is there a way to change the version of Microsoft Edge that the WebView is using?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. You will have to wait until Microsoft updates to the Chromium version of Edge - which they are planning to do this year I believe.

Comment: I see, that's quite unfortunate. After searching the nuget manager a bit I found someone who managed to implement the WebView2 (the current one is mainly on c++ and isn't available in WPF) on WPF. After running WebView2, I'm happy to say that it runs Edge v81 (I'm not sure though if it runs a certain version or runs the latest one installed but regardless, that solved my problem). Nuget package is: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MtrDev.WebView2.Wpf/ if someone else's interested.